# What tech reduces the energy cost of roads?

Tags: civilization-beyond-earth

There is a technology that reduces the upkeep cost of roads and Magrail, but I can't remember what it is, nor can I find it by searching the civopedia.

Comment: There's an affinity that negates the cost.  I'm not sure if it's a tech.

Comment: I think that's what I was thinking of.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not a tech, it's an affinity, supremancy 3 actually

> The level three affinity bonus for supremacy is one of the most
>   useful: pay no maintenance on your roads and magrails.

[More Inforamtion here](http://civilization.wikia.com/wiki/Supremacy_(CivBE))

There is no Tech for it. You can check by going [here](http://civilization.wikia.com/wiki/Tech_Web_%28CivBE%29)
 and searching for "road".